# Context Switch Deadlock

Tags: c#

When I run my application after some Seconds this exception occurred. What is this exception and how can I handle it?

> The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x647f10 to COM
> context 0x648080 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination
> context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or
> processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows
> messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact
> and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory
> usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all
> single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait
> primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump
> messages during long running operations.

Comment: The description of what happened is all in there, although it can be a bit unclear how you triggered it. To get help you will need to be much more specific on what your application does and how it is built.

Comment: I Have Work On Sudoku With Generic Algorithm And maybe a lot of time To find answer and this exception occurred.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio: ContextSwitchDeadlock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578357/visual-studio-contextswitchdeadlock)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This typically occurs if you have something blocking your user interface thread, and are using COM components.

The best approach here is to move your long running operation into a background thread.  This leaves your UI responsive, which also means that the COM messages can pump correctly.  `BackgroundWorker` is a nice tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this results from having a long-running task in the main thread of a windows form. Consider using a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to run the task instead. The immediate benefit of doing this will be that your UI won't appear to freeze while the task is running. You might even look into implementing a progress bar using the [`ProgressChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event.