# Fastest way to generate an xml file with million records in c#

Tags: c#, xml, oracle, odp.net

I have created a Windows application in VS2008 and my requirement is to generate an xml file from a table that fetches a million records. Any pointers on the best possible and fastest approach ?

What is the best possible approach for the same ?

**Option 1 :**   Create a clob in Oracle and fetch it in code.
**Oracle SP :**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetBP (BP OUT XMLTYPE) AS
BEGIN

SELECT XMLRoot(
     XMLElement("MASTER_TABLE",
       XMLAgg(XMLElement("PARTNER",

           XMLForest(PARTNER_NO  as "PARTNER_NO"
                    ,'0001' as "ID" )))
   ), VERSION '1.0', STANDALONE YES) AS "RESULT"
INTO BP
from TABLE1
where YEAR LIKE '%2011-2012%';

END GetBP ;
/
```

**C# code :**

```
private void CreateXML() 
    {
        string oradb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION="
        + "(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XPS)(PORT=1226)))"
        + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DBP0)));"
        + "User Id=scoot;Password=tiger;";

        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(); 
        conn.ConnectionString = oradb;
        conn.Open();

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("BP", OracleDbType.XmlType).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.CommandText = "GetBP";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        string doc = ((Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleXmlType)(cmd.Parameters["BP"].Value)).Value;
        File.WriteAllText("C:/Test/BookInfo.xml", doc);
        cmd.Dispose();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
```

**Option 2 :** Fetch records first and build the xml in c# using XML Writer
**Option 3 :** Fetch records in batches and build the xml
My table T1

> PARTNER_NO  NAME
>   00001       Archie
>   00034       Williams
>   00046       Mark
>   00052       Betty

This is how my XML looks :
[image]

Please give me examples for the best possible approach. Im trying to search for examples in a similar approach. Not able to find one. Option 1 is taking quite sometime to fetch the records.

**Edited**

After trying Option 2, I am getting 'ContextSwitchDeadlock' Exception.
I have also tried to change IDataReader to OracleDataReader to increase the fetchsize but it doesn't help. Any pointers please. Below is my code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PARTNER_NO FROM T1 WHERE YEAR LIKE '%2011-2012%'";  
XmlWriter myWriter = XmlWriter.Create("C:/Test/BookInfo.xml")  
myWriter.WriteStartDocument(true); 
using(OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))  
  {  
    reader.FetchSize = reader.RowSize * 5000;  
    myWriter.WriteStartElement("master_table");
    while(reader.Read())
      {  
         myWriter.WriteStartElement("partner");  
         myWriter.WriteElementString("partner_no", reader[0].ToString());  
         myWriter.WriteElementString("id","0008");  
         myWriter.WriteEndElement();  
      }  
 }  

 myWriter.WriteEndDocument();  
 myWriter.Flush();  
 myWriter.Close();  
 cmd.Dispose()
```

Comment: I would expert,
Expert the data from oracle, using an oracle tool into a XML file (hopefully), if the oracle expect can still only do CSV, then use a tool to convert the CSV into XML.

Comment: FYI, your connection, command, and data adapter should all be in `using` blocks to ensure they are Disposed, even if an exception occurs.

Comment: Thanks John, Never thought about that. Will implement that in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the most intuitive approach, iterate over the `IDataReader` and write to an `XmlWriter` as you go.

I don't know if that's the *fastest* way to do it, but it should be the most memory effective, and you wouldn't need to create batches of any sort:

```
using (IDataReader reader = simpleSelectCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        myWriter.WriteStartElement("PARTNER");
        // write subnodes for this record
        myWriter.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

This shouldn't take you alot of time to make, and may just be fast enough for you.

Comment: This works well when I fetch 100000 records. But when I try fetching all records I am getting ContextSwitchDeadlock exception. What must I do?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578357/visual-studio-contextswitchdeadlock - this may just have to do with the process taking alot of time.

Comment: Thanks Evenhuis. This was a probolem due to connectivity over VPN. Works fine over network.

Comment: In visual studio hit ctrl+alt+e, it'll bring up exception setings, find the one that says 'Managed Debug Settings, and uncheck ContextSwitchDeadlock. That is there to let you know that something COULD be wrong, but in your case it's just a process that takes a long time.

Answer (score 0):

XML consumes always a lot of space and thus much time to be transferred from server to client. So, I assume the fastest way is to select the data by simple SELECT (or as Ref-Cursor from function) and build the XML structure in your client. This would be your Option 2.