# Apache crashes on segmentation fault using mod_wsgi large xml files

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, libxml2

I'm getting a segmentation fault in apache, causing it to restart automatically. The setup is as follows:

- server is a wsgi application generated using python spyne (currently running on localhost)
- soap call is done from a WPF application (.NET)
- using apache 2.4 on windows, with configuration for mod_wsgi as follows:

  LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

  WSGIScriptAlias /WSGI "C:/...etc...pythonservice.py"

  WSGIPythonPath "C:/...etc..."

  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

  Directory "C:/...etc..."

  ```
  Order deny,allow

  Allow from all
  ```

  /Directory

I think the problem might be a default 10MB size limit on XML nodes (libxml2), but I can't find any solution to this problem for my particular set-up.

Answer (score 0):

After a switch to Visual Studio 2013, I got a different error message, namely ContextSwitchDeadlock. This answer solved my problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/612787/4685789

During loading of the large dataset, after every 1000th item I called 
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Join(10) to make sure the application keeps pumping messages.