# Why do I get an exception when my client and server apps are accessing the same stored procedure, yet the code still succeeds?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api, permission-denied, drop-table

I have a Winforms app that calls a method in a Web API app like so:

```
private async Task SavePlatypusComplianceFileOnServer(string year, string month)
{
    string monthAsMM = ReportRunnerConstsAndUtils.GetMonthAsMM(month);
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ReportRunnerConstsAndUtils.SERVER_BASE_ADDRESS);

    String uriToCall = String.Format("/api/PlatypusCompliance/{0}/{1}{2}", _unit, year, monthAsMM);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uriToCall, null);
}
```

Right after making that call (which calls a stored procedure), the client also calls the same stored procedure. It is probably for this reason (I reckon) that I get an exception message that a temporary table referenced in the stored procedure cannot be dropped because I don't have permissions (nor do I have persimmons, but that is by design, as I don't care for them unless they have been used to make cookies).

However, even though the call to the stored procedure is presumably aborted at this point, the process still works: the server (Web API app) successfully does what it is supposed to do (save the data returned from the stored procedure as HTML) and the client (Winforms app) is also successful in generating an Excel spreadsheet and attaching it to an email.

So my question (besides "why is it working when it says it has failed") is: should I care about this exception msg? Should I suppress it so that the user won't see it? Or will it not be seen by the user anyway?

Comment: are u using the same user to connect to the database in the client and the webAPI?

Comment: I guess so; I'm using the same connection string from the same machine.

Comment: can you add the exception and the stacktrace to the question?

Comment: It is simply that a certain table, that is created and then dropped in the Stored Procedure, cannot be dropped because I don't have permission to do so. I also (sometimes) get an exception about two COM objects fighting each other, causing a deadlock.

Comment: The deadlock err was "Context Switch Deadlock"; I fixed it (or swept it under the virtual rug, anyway, by heeding the sage advice at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578357/visual-studio-contextswitchdeadlock