# CustomXMLParts.Add slow due to ContextSwitchDeadlock

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, vsto

I'm getting a

> ContextSwitchDeadlock

when adding a `CustomXMLPart` after performing a `Documents.Add()`.

The same code was working fine last week..

I understand that ContextSwitchDeadlock is caused by a long running operation (this is not a duplicate question).
Why would the CustomXMLParts.Add() command result in a long running operation?

Anyone come across this? and any ideas how to troubleshoot?

> ContextSwitchDeadlock occurred Message: Managed Debugging Assistant
>   'ContextSwitchDeadlock' has detected a problem in 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE'. Additional
>   information: The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context
>   0xfdb520 to COM context 0xfdb468 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns
>   the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non
>   pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without
>   pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative
>   performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non
>   responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To
>   avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should
>   use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and
>   routinely pump messages during long running operations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio: ContextSwitchDeadlock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578357/visual-studio-contextswitchdeadlock)

Comment: Meganaut - question updated to explain that it is not a duplicate

Comment: It would only be a guess without some more information. You should try and show some code surrounding the issue at the very least, otherwise ideally re-create the issue in the most compact piece of code you can and add that to the question.  My instinct is that you have loaded a very large or complex file.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the XML was a lot bigger than I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context switch deadlock can show up when debugging a long running process.  For the most part you can ignore it if the process is expected to be long running.

see [previous stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578357/visual-studio-contextswitchdeadlock)