# Why does C# Winforms stops queriyng the Mysql Database after a couple of queries on a WebHosting?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have a small database used for a C# WinForms with Mysql Net Connector. 
All worked well during localhost development but when I moved it to a GoDaddy hosting I started getting 'ContextSwitchDeadlock'.
I suspect this is because the server is rejecting the new connections as the programs starts okey and open the first connection but as I try to recover data from it, it stops responding. I use this main schema in most of the forms.

```
try
{
    Using(MySqlConnection Connection = new MySqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
   {
      Connection.Open();
      //Fetching Data putting in Combobox,Textbox,DatagridView etc.
   }
}
catch(MySqlException ex)
{
    //Handling
}
```

This is in most forms OnLoad event, so each time a form is opened a new connection is opened. Im aware of Connection pooling so I opened a connection in the main form and in the next one I did just

```
  Using(MySqlConnection Connection = new MySqlConnection())
 {
  Connection.Open();
 }
```

I also disabled the exeption in the debugger options but it just no longer fetch data after some queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio: ContextSwitchDeadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578357/visual-studio-contextswitchdeadlock)

Comment: Disabling the `ContextSwitchDeadlock` Managed Debugging Assistant may let you work around the issue. (I assume you moved just your MySQL Server to GoDaddy hosting, not the Windows Forms application, correct?)

Comment: Yes, I also disabled it in the past sorry I forgot to mention it. But the form just won´t retrieve more data after a couple of queries. It does fetch some data but doesnt finish.

Comment: What's your full connection string (without the password)? Are you setting the `ConnectionTimeout` setting? What happens if you leave that at its default of 15 (or reduce it to, say, 5)? Do you get an exception? If so, what are the full exception details?

Comment: It looks like this one 
  
  Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
Pwd=myPassword;Convert Zero Datetime=True;

Comment: I tried applying the ConnectionTimeOut with five seconds and the first form won´t even start.

Comment: I suspect you're getting a `MySqlException` but it's being caught during form startup and preventing it from being displayed. Try enabling "Break on exceptions" in VS and seeing if you can get the exception details: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: I did, with no different results. My guess is that the server is not permiting more queries. I doesn´t seem to be an issue with the connection but with the amount of queries.