# ContextSwitchDeadlock Exception

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, exception

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express edition.
While executing below code line I will get "ContextSwitchDeadlock was detected" Exception.

Code Line:

```
PID = CheckAndShell(NSISCompilerPath, "/v4 /O""" & LogFile & """ " & NSISFile, AppWinStyle.Hide, , True)
```

I have disabled exception as mentioned in this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/578439/1997066):

```
Under Debug > Exceptions > Managed Debugging Assistants > ContextSwitchDeadlock
```

Still I am getting the above exception.
How to disable this exception?

Comment: If only there was a way to know what happened inside that `CheckAndShell` method.

Comment: CheckAndShell = Shell(Chr(34) & Trim(filePath) & Chr(34) & cmdLine, WindowStyle, waitFlag, lngWait)