# Setting SelectedIndex = 0 in ListBox causing Context Switch Deadlock

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winform with 2 sets of paired ListBoxes like so:

ListProvider -> ListProviderLocations

ListAssistant -> ListAssistantLocations

The basic idea is the user can choose which locations they want to select for both providers and assistant. The data is saved as a preference, which is used on another form to filter the provider and assistant dropdowns base on location.

I need to set the `SelectIndex = 0` for both the ListProvider and ListAssistant dropboxes on `Form.Load()`:

```
listProv.SelectedIndex = 0;
listAsst.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

When I run this code in the debugger, it stalls after the `ListAsst.SelectedIndex = 0;` and eventually throws a Context Switch Deadlock error. If I comment out the `listAsst.SelectedIndex = 0;` or set `listAsst.SelectedIndex = 1;` it works fine again, but neither of these solutions are acceptable.

The code for loading content into each ListBox is identical, except for the list each refererences obviously.

```
private void LoadListProviderLocations () {
   List<Provider> listShort = new List<Provider>();
   listShort = Providers.GetAll();
   this.listProv.Items.Clear();
   for (int i = 0; i < listShort.Count; i++) {
      if (listShort[i].IsHidden == false && listShort[i].AnesthProvType == 1) {
         listProv.Items.Add(Lan.g(this, listShort[i].GetLongDesc()));
      }
      this.listProvLocation.Items.Clear();
      provLocationCur = new List<AnesthLocation>();
      provLocationCur = AnesthLocations.Refresh();
      for (int j = 0; j < provLocationCur.Count; j++) {
         if (provLocationCur[j].Hidden == false) {
         listProvLocation.Items.Add(provLocationCur[j].LocationName);
         }
      }
   }
}

private void LoadListAsstLocations () {
   List<Provider> listShort = new List<Provider>();
   listShort = Providers.GetAll();
   this.listAsst.Items.Clear();
   for (int i = 0; i < listShort.Count; i++) {
      if (listShort[i].IsHidden == false && listShort[i].AnesthProvType == 2) {
         listAsst.Items.Add(Lan.g(this, listShort[i].GetLongDesc()));
      }
      this.listAsstLocation.Items.Clear();
      asstLocationCur = new List<AnesthLocation>();
      asstLocationCur = AnesthLocations.Refresh();
      for (int j = 0; j < asstLocationCur.Count; j++) {
         if (asstLocationCur[j].Hidden == false) {               
         listAsstLocation.Items.Add(asstLocationCur[j].LocationName);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I'm completely baffled as to why this would be?

What I've tried: Set `listAsst.SelectedItem = 1` which clears the deadlock but is not an acceptable solution

Edit: in response to @Steve Py below, here is the designer code for both:

```
            // 
            // listProv
            // 
            this.listProv.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(41, 193);
            this.listProv.Name = "listProv";
            this.listProv.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(242, 173);
            this.listProv.TabIndex = 4;
            this.listProv.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listProv_SelectedIndexChanged);
            // 
            // listAsst
            // 
            this.listAsst.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.listAsst.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(19, 343);
            this.listAsst.Name = "listAsst";
            this.listAsst.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(242, 199);
            this.listAsst.TabIndex = 13;
            this.listAsst.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listAsst_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Edit: for Ralf

```
        private void listAsst_SelectedIndexChanged (object sender, EventArgs e) {
            try {
                provNum = AnesthLocations.GetAnesthProviderNum(listAsst.SelectedItem.ToString());
            }
            catch { }

            listAnesthProvider = AnesthProviders.Refresh();
            for (int i = 0; i < listAnesthProvider.Count; i++) {
                if (listAnesthProvider[i].ProviderNum == provNum) {
                    long locationNum = listAnesthProvider[i].LocationNum;
                    string command = "SELECT * FROM anesthlocation WHERE LocationNum = " + POut.Long(locationNum);
                    asstLocationName = AnesthLocations.GetLocationName(locationNum);
                    foreach (var item in asstLocationCur){
                        for (int j = 0; j < listAsstLocation.Items.Count; j++) {
                            if (asstLocationName == item.LocationName) {
                                listAsstLocation.SetSelected(j, true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                }

            }
            RefreshListAsstLocations();

        }
```

Comment: Do you have event handlers for On Change on either/both listboxes? If so, please add that code.

Comment: I tried deleting the listAsst ListBox and re-adding it but I get the same result

Comment: Does this happen allso when you are not debugging the code but just normally execute the app? This context switch exceptions are often just internal debugger things. And when you have setup your debugger environment to listen/catch all exceptions you get to see things that are often just silent exceptions that occur but do not matter. You just decided to see them and you are then confused but shouldn't.

Comment: The software hangs when running the app as well. There aren't any long running processes in this code.

Comment: THen we need to know what happens in listAsst_SelectedIndexChanged.

Comment: You call SetSelected in the event so the SelectedIndexChanged is called again. Presumably you build some sort of endless loop. Without debugger its will just hang and with debugger the debugger will bark at some point as its running out of resources following your endless loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/578439/6843577

Comment: Also, iterating through the entire list every time an item is selected can be excessive, especially if these lists contain a lot of items. If these lists are multi-select then there isn't much that can be done about that, but if they are single-select then add a `break;` after you find the item you want and act on it to exit the loop. For larger sets consider not loading everything into a drop-down or list, rather use something like a more intelligent asynchronous search that can fill in matches to choose from. The error is an indicator that the loops/loading is doing too much on UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the "SelectedItem" property, which functions effectively when you bind the item source object of the list to a collection. I strongly suggest adopting this approach by setting the ItemSource of the Providers and Assistants list. Additionally, configure the DisplayMember and ValueMember of both lists. By doing so, you'll simplify the process of handling the SelectChange event for each list, making it easier to populate the locations list.

Comment: Thanks, but not sure how I would do this? I want the first assistant in the list to be selected, but I won't know the text string the user has assigned to that fist assistant

Comment: Firstly to use this approach you need to set the list itemsource in the form load 
listAsst.ItemSource = Providers.GetAll();
then set the display and value members
listAsst.ValueMemeber="Id";
listAsst.DisplayMember = "name or whatever";
listAsst.SelectedValue = the id of needed item

Answer (score -1):

#### Activated

I don't quite have enough context to know if this would work, but try moving the code to form_activated. I *think* that only runs once, when first activated. If not (and it resets when you switch back to the window), just set a boolean at formlevel like 'bool firstactivation = false;' and then check in in the form_Activated for false and set it to true after resetting.

#### Application.DoEvents();

You *could* try this in between the two calls (in load or activated). it *could* work. it *could* screw things up, too! Worth a try though.

Answer (score -1):

OK, it was none of the above.

There was code in the loops that inserted records and it would insert records each time I loaded the form, totally 25,000 in all which explains the hang.

Once I fixed that insertion code, the problem disappeared.

I really appreciate all of your input.